# how to change (strip) multiple column names using MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table with column names like so:
    BLAH_Q1_NAME, BLAH_BLAH_Q2_AGE, BLAH_UGLY_BLAH_Q3_DATE_OF_BIRTH, etc.

I want to be able to change the column names to strip away all of the name before the "Q#" portion, such that I end up with column names that look like so:
    Q1_NAME, Q2_AGE, Q3_DATE_OF_BIRTH, etc.

There are 40+ variables in this table, which prohibits me simply doing this manually.  (I hope!!)  Is there any way to do this in MySQL?  Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure what your question is. Are you trying to rename 40+ columns?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to rename all 40 columns.

Answer (score 0):

There's no MySQL command to let you quickly rename 40 columns, but you can just grab a random scripting language to help you write a query to do that for you.

```
$ perl -le'print "alter table MyTable ". (join ", ", map { "change BLAH_Q${_}_NAME Q${_}_NAME INT" } 1..40)'
```

(truncated) output:

```
alter table MyTable change BLAH_Q1_NAME Q1_NAME INT, change BLAH_Q2_NAME Q2_NAME INT, change BLAH_Q3_NAME Q3_NAME INT, change BLAH_Q4_NAME Q4_NAME INT, change BLAH_Q5_NAME Q5_NAME INT
```